# How to stop user for using same username which already exist in my local storage?

Tags: javascript

```js
var labelsarray = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
var inputsarray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var array = [];
function agecal() {
 var Bdate = inputsarray[4].value;
 var Bday = +new Date(Bdate).getFullYear();
 var age = (new Date().getFullYear() - Bday);
 inputsarray[5].value = age;
}


function subm() {
 var users = {
  FirstName: inputsarray[0].value,
  LastName: inputsarray[1].value,
  UserName: inputsarray[2].value,
  Password: inputsarray[3].value,
  DateofBirth: inputsarray[4].value,
  Age: inputsarray[5].value,
  Purpose: ""
 };
 
 if (inputsarray[6].checked === true) {
  users.Gender = "Male";
 } else if (inputsarray[7].checked === true) {
  users.Gender = "Female";
 }
 
 if (inputsarray[8].checked === true) users.Purpose += " Storing Apps";
 if (inputsarray[9].checked === true) users.Purpose += " Storing Sites";
 if (inputsarray[10].checked === true) users.Purpose += " Fun";
 
 array.push(users);
 localStorage.setItem("Users Data: ", JSON.stringify(array));

 var item = localStorage.getItem("Users Data: ");
 var arrayobjfromls = JSON.parse(item);
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayobjfromls.length; i++) {
  if (inputsarray[2].value === arrayobjfromls[i].UserName) {
   alert("This username is already in use. Please try another.");
   localStorage.removeItem(arrayobjfromls[i]);
   
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div>
 <center>
  <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" onsubmit="subm();">
   <label for="fname">First Name:</label>&emsp;
   <input type="text" id="fname" />
   <br/>
   <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>&emsp;
   <input type="text" id="lname" />
   <br/>
   <label for="uname">User Name:</label>&emsp;
   <input type="text" id="uname" />
   <br/>
   <label for="pass">Password:</label>&emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;
   <input type="password" id="pass" />
   <br/>
   <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="date" id="dob" onchange="agecal();" />
   <br/>
   <label>Age:</label>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
   <input type="text" id="age" disabled="disabled" />
   <br/>
   <span>Gender:</span>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" />
   <label for="male">Male</label>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" />
   <label for="female">Female</label>
   <br/>
   <p>For what purpose(s) you are making account?</p>
   <input type="checkbox" id="app" name="purpose" value="storingapps" />
   <label for="app">Storing Apps</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="site" name="purpose" value="storingsites" />
   <label for="site">Storing Sites</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="fun" name="purpose" value="fun" />
   <label for="fun">Fun</label>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
  </form>
 </center>
</div>
```

Please help me I want to stop user for using username which already present in my local storage by showing an alert and also I don't want to send data to local storage in which username is same of that data which is already present in my local storage...so that my local storage contain only those objects which have different usernames.

Comment: Haven't you just tried using `... localStorage.getItem("Users Data: ") ... ` then check the array? - Or you could store an array of usernames, then check against that array, as you could then just use `... array.indexof(username) ...`, which in theory it would be quicker than checking through an array of objects.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'i couldn't get you'? I'm assuming you mean I didn't get you/what you mean?

Comment: I mean I can't understand what are you saying can you explain me with code. It would be helpful..

Comment: Sure thing, I'll show you what I mean in a demo now...

Comment: Thank you so much..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168224/discussion-between-arham-awan-and-jo3-w3b-d3v).

Answer (score 1):

You're already checking for this; you're just doing it after you've already added the new user. Do the check first:

```
var item = localStorage.getItem("Users Data: ");
var arrayobjfromls = JSON.parse(item);
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayobjfromls.length; i++) {
    if(users.UserName === arrayobjfromls[i].UserName) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}


if ( found ) {
    alert("This username is already in use. Please try another.");
} else {
    array.push( users );
    localStorage.setItem("Users Data: ", JSON.stringify(array));
}
```

Comment: Probably the better way to do it! - As I mentioned above, you could just store another item in the local storage, i.e. `usernames` and just let it be an array of strings, you could then use `indexof(...)`, but then you're using more storage than necessary, so... :P

Comment: Still not working it is showing error at arrayobjfromls.length

Comment: What error? What value does `arrayobjfromls` have at the time?